# Nextjs 13 App router CMS setup - Compiling static pages

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Setup: Nextjs 13 using App router.
Aim: A path that will fetch blog pages from the api and list them out.
Problem: I can't compile my app for production because nextjs tries to call the api which doesn't exist yet (first deploy) or could be out of sync due to code/db changes (subsequent deploys).

I am using a headless CMS to host a blog and some other pages. The majority of my site is set up to work with a fallback path that catches all (as an editor could publish a page on any url, nextjs doesn't know what page type or data to show at build time).

However, as an optimisation, I though I might add a hardcoded path for `/blog/`. This will have lots of static content, like a title and intro, and then list out articles. These articles are fetched from the CMS.

I am using nextjs 13 and the app router so this is as simple as adding an `await fetch()` call to my component. I have then added a wrapper component that adds a Suspense boundary so that nextjs can show a loading UI while it talks to the CMS. All this is happening server side, not client side.

```
export const _ArticleList = async () => {
    articles = await fetchArticles(..., { cache: "no-store" })

    return (
        // Article list UI
    )
}

export const ArticleList = async () => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingUI />}>
            <_ArticleList />
        </Suspense>
    )
}
```

What I want to happen is for nextjs to take advantage of knowing that `/blog/` exists to do things like preload any `<Link>`s to it and to create an optimised entry point bundle for it.

As the CMS is not available at build time (and you couldn't just build in a static list of links for a blog where editors are free to publish content anyway) I'd like nextjs to precompile to suspense state and still fill in the fetch results dynamically when requests come in.

What happens is the build fails because nextjs tries to fetch the articles.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want or do I just need to give up and use the fallback path for my entire site and render everything dynamically with no built-in static help?

Thanks.